# Running mkdir -p in parallel under Mac OS X, quits before directory is created

Tags: macos, mkdir

I have a Makefile with multiple jobs.

Each job does a `mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)`, to ensure the object directory exists before running `gcc`.

However, the `mkdir -p` sometimes does not ensure the directory exists before returning.  I assume there is some sort of race condition going on.  And then the compiler fails, as it can't write to the output file.

Is there a platform agnostic way of doing the `mkdir -p` so that this race condition doesn't occur?

---

This failure seems to only happen under OS X.
Question got sent to Stack Overflow, but really a sysadmin question.

---

```
# script named 'test'
if [ "$1" == "run" ] ; then
  rm -rf XXX

  NOW=`date +%s`
  echo Now: $NOW
  THEN=`echo "$NOW + 10" | bc`
  RUNAT=`date -r $THEN +"%m%d%H%M.%S"`
  echo $RUNAT

  for i in {1..75}; do
    ./test $THEN &
    sleep 0.05
  done
  wait
  exit 0
fi

THEN=$1
# make sure things are cached
NOW=`python -c'import time; print repr(time.time())'`
NOW=`python -c'import time; print repr(time.time())'`

AMOUNT=`echo "$THEN - $NOW" | bc`
echo sleeping $AMOUNT
sleep $AMOUNT

mkdir -p XXX/YYY/ZZZ
touch XXX/YYY/ZZZ/hi
```

I wrote the above bash script, but it doesn't produce the predicted error.  I will put the touch in the makefile, perhaps it will elucidate what is going on.

The makefile's CC statement looks like so:

```
$(OBJPATH)/%.o : %.cpp
        mkdir -p $(dir $@)
        @sleep 0.1
        $(CPP) $(INCPATH) $(_FLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

The `@sleep` statement is there to possibly wait for the race condition to fix itself, but perhaps there is no race condition after all.

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: `mkdir -p` should not exit before creating the directory (although it might fail for some reason), so there really shouldn't be a race condition here. I suspect something else is going wrong, but without more information I have no idea what that might be. Can you trim it down to a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (e.g. trim irrelevant stuff, replace the compile command with `touch fileininoutputdirectory`, etc), and add that to the question?

Comment: Probably you have not set up the dependencies necessary for `make` to know that it must serialize the `mkdir -p` and `gcc` steps. It is running them in parallel, or maybe even doing the latter before the former. We won't be able to help unless we see the make rules in question.

Comment: Ken - it is definitely performing the `gcc` step after the `mkdir` step.  It is a race condition between processes, all of them simultaneously `mkdir -p` and then write to a file within the directory..   Gordon - I'm trying to think how to setup a simple example.

Comment: I have added a `touch $(dir $@)/direxists` in the rule for the cpp -> o files before the compilation, and now the makefile does not die.

This is definitely a kludge, but so far I have not hit the error.  What this actually means, I am not sure... I will update again, if I do see the error with the included kludge.

Comment: I had a similar problem to you and used `mkdir -p`. However, some of my colleagues use Mac and `mkdir -p` did not work as reliably there. The actual situation was a bit more complex but [the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36016777/1609556) may be of use to you.

Comment: I am currently using: 
`$(OBJPATH)/%.o : %.cpp
        -@mkdir -p $(dir $@)
        @while [ ! -e $(dir $@) ]; do sleep 0.1; done
        $(CPP) $(INCPATH) $(_FLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
`

seems to work...  could just be coincidence