# writing a recursive make recipe with prerequisite on parent directory

Tags: recursion, makefile, metaprogramming, gnu-make

I am trying to write a recursive make recipe.  In this recipe, each target is dependent on a file with an equal name on the parent directory.  A minimal (non-working) example:

```
foo/.dirstamp:
  mkdir $(dir $@)
  touch $@

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%/.dirstamp: $$(dir $$*).dirstamp
  mkdir $(dir $@)
  touch $@
```

With this example, I would expect `make foo/bar/qux/lol/.dirstamp` to generate the whole directory tree (if it does not exist), touching all `.dirstamp` files along the way. However, it does not work:

```
$ ls # note that there is nothing, make is meant to create the dir tree
Makefile
$ make --debug=v foo/bar/qux/lol/.dirstamp
GNU Make 4.0
[...]
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile 'Makefile'...
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file 'foo/bar/qux/lol/.dirstamp'.
 File 'foo/bar/qux/lol/.dirstamp' does not exist.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'foo/bar/qux/lol/.dirstamp'.
Must remake target 'foo/bar/qux/lol/.dirstamp'.
make: *** No rule to make target 'foo/bar/qux/lol/.dirstamp'.  Stop.
```

It works fine as long as the recursive recipe only needs to be expanded twice, e.g., `make foo/bar/.dirstamp` works fine.

How can this work for an arbitrary number of levels? How can I handle a recursive expansion for the target and prerequisites names?

Note: my real problem is that the prerequisites of my recipes are in a root
directory different from the target so I am using the recipe above to duplicate the directory tree. I know about `mkdir -p` <strike>which seems to work fine in GNU systems. I am still interested on knowing how I would solve the recursion problem for arbitrary levels.</strike> which no longer works because part of the team is using Mac and mounting this directories over smb.

**More details on the actual problem:** prerequisites are in `data/x/y/z` while targets go into `results/x/y/z`. However, the `results` directory tree does not exist and needs to be created as needed.  To solve this, I made the creation of parent directories an order-only prerequisite (via the `.dirstamp` files on my minimal example above).

- can't copy `data` into `results`, that's several TB of data;
- can't have the targets created in `data`, that's read-only;
- can't use `mkdir -p` because the `results` directory will not be local, mounted over smb, and others may use non-GNU systems;

Comment: Would you be willing to use recursive Make? [sinister music]

Comment: make won't apply a rule more than once. That's a built-in (intentional) limitation. Without working around that with manual recursion or manually building the set of targets and using a static pattern rule (which may or may not actually work I'm not sure) there's not much you can do about this.

Comment: @Beta how would that work? Note that I'm using this to create the directory tree, those directories do not exist and therefore can't have a Makefile.

Comment: @EtanReisner so I'd need to create a list of all possible dirstamp files first instead of hoping that they're deduced from N levels of recursion? Hmm... I will try that.

Comment: I'm not sure what SMB has to do with the `mkdir -p` thing but OS X `mkdir` has the `-p` flag (and seems to have for a while from a quick look).

Comment: @EtanReisner yes, OSX's `mkdir` has the `-p` flag but is not as reliable. These directories are remote shares and mounted via SMB. On my GNU/Linux systems, `mkdir -p` works fine. On Mac it only creates the first directory and then errors. Also, I will want these jobs to run in parallel. GNU's `mkdir` is thread-safe. I'm not sure about Mac systems but googling for it gives anecdotal evidence that it could be an issue.

Comment: A tool or function call being thread-safe doesn't have *anything* to do with multiple processes using the tool or function at the same time. Those are *entirely* unrelated concepts. What error do you get from `mkdir -p` on OS X? That's strikes me as odd (but a different issue so we can leave it alone).

Comment: @EtanReisner you're right. Point is, I saw people complaining about `mkdir -p` not always working in parallel in OSX. On the topic of smb in OSX,  the error is only `No such file or directory`. The result is: only the lowest level directory gets created. Repeated calls of `mkdir -p`  creates the whole path, one directory each time. These OSX systems are not mine (are some of my colleagues) so I didn't bother investigating much on the reasons. You are right, it's a different issue. And if they are interested, they can ask about it and solve it if they want too.

Comment: I was thinking of having your one makefile invoke itself with different arguments, but it looks as if you have a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 3):

After an hint from @EtanReisner on the question:

> make won't apply a rule more than once. That's a built-in (intentional) limitation. Without working around that with manual recursion or manually building the set of targets and using a static pattern rule (which may or may not actually work I'm not sure) there's not much you can do about this.

I worked up this solution:

```
RESULT_DIRS := $(patsubst data/%, results/%, $(shell find data/* -type d -print))
DIRSTAMPS := $(addsuffix /.dirstamp, $(RESULT_DIRS))

results/.dirstamp:
    mkdir $(dir $@)
    touch $@

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(DIRSTAMPS): $$(dir $$(patsubst %/.dirstamp, %, $$@)).dirstamp
    mkdir $(dir $@)
    touch $@
```

It will duplicate the `data` directory tree in `results` as the dirstamp files are required. They are required by making them prerequisites of the other recipes (note the `|` which makes them order-only prerequisites):

```
results/%/foo.analysis: data/%/foo.data | results/%/.dirstamp
    $(SOME_ANALYSIS_PROGRAM) $^ > $@
```